# Scheduling tasks with shared resources using logic programming

Tags: prolog, clpfd

```
Time 5, 3, 8, 2, 7, 3, 9, 3, 3, 5, 7
```

You have to schedule players (which uses Time) to three different showers. Get the best solution.
So far, my solution is:

```
use_module(library(clpfd)).

shower(S, E, D, Done) :- 
    D = [5, 3, 8, 2, 7, 3, 9, 3, 3, 5, 7],
    R =  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    length(D, N),
    length(S, N),
    length(E, N),
    domain(S, 0, 100),
    domain(E, 0, 100),
    Done in 0..100,
    ready(E, Done),
    tasks(S, D, E, R, Tasks),
    cumulative(Tasks, [limit(3)]),
    labeling([minimize(Done)], [Done|S]).

tasks([], [], [], [], []).
tasks([S|Ss], [D|Ds], [E|Es], [R|Rs], [T|Ts]) :-
    T = task(S, D, E, R, 0),
    tasks(Ss, Ds, Es, Rs, Ts).

ready([], _).
ready([E|Es], Done) :-
    Done #>= E,
    ready(Es, Done).
```

If I run the program:

```
?- shower(S,D).
```

it will print:

```
D = 19,
S = [0,0,0,3,5,5,8,8,11,14,12]
```

Done is the total time (maximum time), S is the time of start for each of the tasks, E is the ending time for each of the tasks while D is the duration of the tasks.

So far, so good.

But now, I am struggling with the other things. Precisely:

1) How can I also print which player is using which shower?

2) How can I limit one shower to be able to run a maximum of four players?

I am a total newbie to Prolog, and it is quite likely that this might be the last program I am writing on it. I managed so far to do this, but I need to finish this (you guess it, it is an assignment). It is the very last thing I have to do on this course, and I haven't ever done any constraint logic programming before.

Thanks for reading and eventually replying on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `cumulatives/[2,3]` constraint instead of the `cumulative/1` constraint, then you will get the assigned machine for 'free'.

By use of `cumulatives` each single machine can be given individual resource capacity.

This shows your problem solved by use of `cumulatives`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).

go( Ss, Es, Ms) :-

    Ss = [S1, S2, S3, S4,S5,S6,S7], %Starttimes
    Es = [E1, E2, E3, E4,E5,E6,E7], %Endtimeds
    Ms = [M1, M2, M3, M4,M5,M6,M7], %MachineIds

    domain(Ss, 0, 10),
    domain(Es, 0, 10),
    domain(Ms, 1, 4),

    Tasks = [
        task(  S1, 3,  E1,  1, M1 ), 
        task(  S2, 4,  E2,  1, M2 ), 
        task(  S3, 1,  E3,  1, M3 ), 
        task(  S4, 1,  E4,  1, M4 ), 
        task(  S5, 1,  E5,  1, M5 ), 
        task(  S6, 1,  E6,  1, M6 ), 
        task(  S7, 4,  E7,  1, M7 )
    ],

    %All machines has resource capacity = 1
    Machines = [
        machine(  1, 1 ),
        machine(  2, 1 ),
        machine(  3, 1 ), 
        machine(  4, 1 ) 
    ],

    cumulatives(Tasks, Machines, [bound(upper)] ),
    maximum( MaxEndTime, Es ),

    %The variables to lable:
    append([Ms, Ss ], Vars),

    labeling( [minimize(MaxEndTime)], Vars).
```

And when launched you get:

```
| ?- go( Ss, Es, Ms) .
Ss = [0,0,3,0,1,2,0],
Es = [3,4,4,1,2,3,4],
Ms = [1,2,1,3,3,3,4] ?
```

As you can see:
task 1 is assigned to machine 1 with start time 0
task 2 is assigned to machine 2 with start time 0
task 3 is assigned to machine 1 with start time 3
.
.

Comment: If it isn't too much work, may I ask you how to do it?  I don't understand it from the given example.

Thanks!

Comment: I have extended my answer to include a full example based of the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Nice question, +1!

Here is one way to solve it: Suppose you have already found a schedule that satisfies the resource limit. Then you simply describe what must hold in addition so that the tasks can be allocated to the machines in the desired way.

For example:

```
distribution(Starts, Ends, Machines) :-
        pairs_keys_values(Pairs, Starts, Ends),
        length(Ms0, 4),
        maplist(=(0-[]), Ms0),
        foldl(task_machines0_machines, Pairs, Ms0, Ms1),
        pairs_values(Ms1, Machines0),
        maplist(reverse, Machines0, Machines1),
        msort(Machines1, Machines).

task_machines0_machines(Start-End, Ms0, [End-[Start|Starts]|Ms1]) :-
        Start #>= OccupiedUntil,
        select(OccupiedUntil-Starts, Ms0, Ms1),
        L #=< 2,
        length(Starts, L).
```

`Machines` contains one list for each machine, where each list in turn consists of the starting times of the tasks allocated to that machine.

*I leave more precisely identifying the tasks as a simple exercise.*

Example usage and its result:

```
?- shower(Starts, Ends, _, _), distribution(Starts, Ends, Machines).
Starts = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
Ends = [3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
Machines = [[0], [0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 3]] .
```

Let us see how many unique solutions there are for a total duration of **4** time slots, which we already know to be the minimum due to the resource limit alone:

```
?- setof(Ms, Starts^Ends^Ds^(shower(Starts, Ends, Ds, 4),
                             distribution(Starts, Ends, Ms)),
         Mss),
   length(Mss, L).
Mss = [[[0], [0, 1], [0, 3], [0, 3]], ...]
L = 14.
```

This is a *lower bound* on the number of actually unique solutions, which we can only compute if we take unique task identifiers into account instead of starting times.

I have done this and found *20 ways* to distribute the tasks subject to all constraints, using the machines interchangeably:

```
distributions([
    [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6],[7]], [[1],[2,4],[3,5,6],[7]], [[1],[2,5],[3,4,6],[7]],
    [[1],[2,6],[3,4,5],[7]], [[1,3],[2],[4,5,6],[7]], [[1,3],[2,4],[5,6],[7]],
    [[1,3],[2,5],[4,6],[7]], [[1,3],[2,6],[4,5],[7]], [[1,4],[2],[3,5,6],[7]],
    [[1,4],[2,3],[5,6],[7]], [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[7]], [[1,4],[2,6],[3,5],[7]],
    [[1,5],[2],[3,4,6],[7]], [[1,5],[2,3],[4,6],[7]], [[1,5],[2,4],[3,6],[7]],
    [[1,5],[2,6],[3,4],[7]], [[1,6],[2],[3,4,5],[7]], [[1,6],[2,3],[4,5],[7]],
    [[1,6],[2,4],[3,5],[7]], [[1,6],[2,5],[3,4],[7]]
  ]).
```

Comment: I know that you left it as an exercise for me, but I really don't have any idea how to do it. If you can give me the code, I will be very grateful. I don't usually post assignment related questions on stackoverflow, but I am desperate considering that it is an alien language for me, and I don't have months to master it. I worked almost 10 days to get so far (which is emberrasing).

Regardless if you reply or not, I thank you a lot for spending time on me. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code, since I'm using SWI-prolog...

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

shower(Durations, NumMachines, Starts, Done) :- 
    sum_list(Durations, Max),
    Done in 0..Max,
    maplist(task(Max, Done), Durations, Tasks, Starts),
    cumulative(Tasks, [limit(NumMachines)]),
    labeling([min(Done)], [Done|Starts]).

task(Max, Done, Duration, task(Start, Duration, End, 1, 0), Start) :-
    MaxStart is Max-Duration,
    Start in 0..MaxStart,
    End #= Start + Duration, %End in 0..Max,
    Done #>= End.
```

that is, now shower/4 expects the durations and the number of machines, and outputs the start times and minimized makespan (this should be the appropriate terminology).

```
1 ?- shower([3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4], 4, S, D).
S = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
D = 4 ;
S = [0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0],
D = 4 
...
```

There are a lot of possibilities, fixed the lower bound

```
?- aggregate(count,S^shower([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4], 4, S, 4),N).
N = 348.
```

to print all:

```
?- forall(shower([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4], 4, S, 4), writeln(S)).
```

A simple allocation of machines to tasks:

```
allocate_machines(Machines, Starts, Durations, Gantt) :-
    findall(M-[], member(M, Machines), Pool),
    distribute(Starts, Durations, Pool, Gantt).

distribute([], [], Allocated, Allocated).
distribute([S|Ss], [D|Ds], Pool, Allocated) :-
    select(M-Duties, Pool, Reduced),
    \+ busy(S, Duties),
    length(Duties, L), L < 3,
    append(Duties, [S/D], Updated),
    distribute(Ss, Ds, [M-Updated|Reduced], Allocated).

busy(S, [Sd/Dd|_]) :- S < Sd+Dd, !.
busy(S, [_|Ds]) :- busy(S, Ds).
```

Answer (score 0):

@MortenM

I made some changes to your code, to make is more suitable for my restriction (basically, different time spend for the tasks - like I had in original specifications, add the fourth machine - and more importantly, tasks start at time 0, not time 1). The code now looks:

```
go( Ss, Es, Ms) :-

Ss = [S1, S2, S3, S4,S5,S6,S7], %Starttimes
Es = [E1, E2, E3, E4,E5,E6,E7], %Endtimeds
Ms = [M1, M2, M3, M4,M5,M6,M7], %MachineIds


domain(Ss, 0, 20),
domain(Es, 0, 20),
domain(Ms, 1, 10),

%All task has duration = 1
Tasks = [
    task(  S1, 3,  E1,  1, M1 ), 
    task(  S2, 3,  E2,  1, M2 ), 
    task(  S3, 1,  E3,  1, M3 ), 
    task(  S4, 1,  E4,  1, M4 ), 
    task(  S5, 1,  E5,  1, M5 ), 
    task(  S6, 1,  E6,  1, M6 ), 
    task(  S7, 4,  E7,  1, M7 )
],

%All machines has resource capacity = 1
Machines = [
    machine(  1, 1 ),
    machine(  2, 1 ),
    machine(  3, 1 ),
    machine(  4, 1)
],

cumulatives(Tasks, Machines, [bound(upper)] ),
 maximum( MaxEndTime, Es ),

%The variables to lable:
append([Ms, Ss ], Vars),
labeling( [minimize(MaxEndTime)], Vars).
```

While, when I run it, the results (correct results) are:

```
?- go(Ss,Es,Ms).
Ss = [0,0,3,3,0,1,0],
Es = [3,3,4,4,1,2,4],
Ms = [1,2,1,2,3,3,4] ?
```

The only problem is that the program isn't giving me other solutions. This isn't the unique solution but it looks that the program is finding only this one. No idea why or how I can change that.

Thanks a lot, you're a lifesaver.

NB: I made this post before you made your final change :)

Comment: If you want to get all solution where MaxEndTime=4, you could post a constraint on MaxEndTime + replace [minimize(MaxEndTime)] with [] and thereafter use ; to get each single solution.

Comment: Made the changes you mentioned, and it is working.

Thank you a lot for spending all this time on me!